# Pycharm Error - 'pip' is not an internal or external command nor is it a running program or batch file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm, anaconda

I can use the "pip" in cmd, but when I use "pip" or "python" in the PyCharm terminal the error appears:

```
pip is not an internal or external command nor is it a running program or batch file.
```

But when I check the Interpreter, pip is exists.
[image]

Comment: you are likely confusing terminal with console.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also, but only for one of my projects. I was able to resolve it by removing my venv and creating a new one.

Preferences > Project > Python Interpreter > Add Python Interpreter ("Show All" from dropdown, then "+" icon) > Virtualenv Environment > New Environment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).