# 'Pip' recognized in Command Prompt but not in PyCharm terminal

Tags: python, windows, path, pip, pycharm

When I try to run pip in the Windows Command Prompt, `pip -V` works fine, but when I try to run it in PyCharm terminal I get `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

My Path environmental variables are set for:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\
```

The main difference I can think of is that the PyCharm terminal and project opens on `D:`, and my path variables are set to `C:` but I don't know why that would affect it. I have recently uninstalled and reinstalled both PyCharm and Python (a previous version) if that helps, but I made it a point to not import any settings.

This is a potential duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533269/pycharm-error-pip-is-not-an-internal-or-external-command-nor-is-it-a-running) but it's also unresolved.

Comment: Did you configure your python interpreter ? ....maybe if you still having problems, you can install or interact with pip in your command prompt directly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer to my own question: when things don't make sense, try turning it off and on again. Problem was fixed with a restart.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Preferences -> Project -> Python Interpreter settings:

[image: Project Interpreter Settings]

(sorry for Mac screenshots and paths, but not near my Windows PC atm but should give general idea of a possible problem area and how to correct)

Comment: This didn't work. Fortunately, however, the problem appears to have resolved itself with a restart (good 'ol windows).

Comment: U save my time bro, it worked after changing and restarting, thanks @Ken Colton

Answer (score 0):

I found a case where powershell was somewhat disabled due to security policies, there was nothing one could do to make it work, period. But that is not the end, if you just are starting with pycharm just search how to select the default terminal to cmd.

In PyCharm open Terminal from the left botton terminal icon, or ALT+F12. There at the top bar of the terminal itself there is a V icon/button with a Settings option, that when pressed will take one to a window where at Application Settings / Shell path you can set the default Shell path to c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe and next time it will use cmd and find pip.